Sort list of keys (Python)
I have a dictionary with the following keys in a list (ListOfKeys = list(MyDict.keys())):
['1002', '1008', '1012', '1016', '1020', '1026', '103', '1030', '1034', '1038', '1044', '1048', '1052', '1056', '107', '111', '1124', '1128', '1132', '1136', '1142', '1146', '1150', '1154', '1160', '1164', '1168', '117', '1172', '1178', '1182', '1186', '1190', '1196', '1200', '1204', '1208', '121', '1214', '1218', '1222', '1226', '1232', '1236', '1240', '1244', '125', '129', '1291', '135', '1369', '139', '1410', '1414', '1418', '1422', '1428', '143', '1432', '1436', '1440', '1446', '1450', '1454', '1458', '1464', '1468', '147', '1472', '1476', '1482', '1486', '1490', '1494', '1500', '1504', '1508', '1512', '1518', '1522', '1526', '153', '1530', '157', '161', '1633', '1637', '1641', '1645', '165', '1651', '1655', '1659', '1663', '1669', '1673', '1677', '1681', '1687', '1691', '1695', '1699', '1705', '1709', '1713', '1717', '1723', '1727', '1731', '1735', '1741', '1745', '1749', '1753', '2016', '2020', '2024', '2028', '2034', '2038', '2042', '2046', '2052', '2056', '2060', '2064', '2070', '2074', '2078', '2082', '2088', '2092', '2096', '2100', '2106', '2110', '2114', '2118', '2124', '2128', '2132', '2136', '2185', '2221', '2263', '2301', '2305', '2309', '2313', '2319', '2323', '2327', '2331', '2337', '2341', '2345', '2349', '2355', '2359', '2363', '2367', '2373', '2377', '2381', '2385', '2391', '2395', '2399', '2403', '2409', '2413', '2417', '2421', '2524', '2528', '2532', '2536', '2542', '2546', '2550', '2554', '2560', '2564', '2568', '2572', '2578', '2582', '2586', '2590', '2596', '2600', '2604', '2608', '2614', '2618', '2622', '2626', '2632', '2636', '2640', '2644', '2721', '2725', '2729', '2733', '2739', '2743', '2747', '2751', '2757', '2761', '2765', '2769', '2775', '2779', '2783', '2787', '2793', '2797', '2801', '2805', '2811', '2815', '2819', '2823', '2829', '2833', '2837', '2841', '2907', '2911', '2915', '2919', '2925', '2929', '2933', '2937', '2943', '2947', '2951', '2955', '2961', '2965', '2969', '2973', '2979', '2983', '2987', '2991', '2997', '3001', '3005', '3009', '3015', '3019', '3023', '3027', '3070', '3115', '3148', '436', '45', '475', '49', '516', '520', '524', '528', '53', '534', '538', '542', '546', '552', '556', '560', '564', '57', '570', '574', '578', '582', '588', '592', '596', '600', '606', '610', '614', '618', '624', '628', '63', '632', '636', '67', '71', '739', '743', '747', '75', '751', '757', '761', '765', '769', '775', '779', '783', '787', '793', '797', '801', '805', '81', '811', '815', '819', '823', '829', '833', '837', '841', '847', '85', '851', '855', '859', '89', '93', '936', '940', '944', '948', '954', '958', '962', '966', '972', '976', '980', '984', '99', '990', '994', '998']

I want to sort this list in increasing order.
I have already tried, unsuccessfully the following: ListOfKeys.sort() and MyDictOrder = {iDict: MyDict[iDict] for iDict in ListOfKeys} Any other idea? Maybe I should start sorting the original dictionary (how)?

Your keys are strings. So sorting them will sort them alphabetically. You want to sort them by their integer value. ListOfKeys.sort(key=lambda value: int(value))

@Homer512 ...key=int
